# Error getting too many character literals

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

```
var query = from s in bv.baParticularHeaders
            from v in bv.baPlanColumnStructures
            where x.Contains(s.Particular_Num)
            select new LevelList
            {
                Value =  'Level ' + LTRIM(Rtrim(Convert(Char,P.Level_Num))) + ' - ',
                id = 'Column ' + LTRIM(Rtrim(Convert(Char,P.Column_Num))) + ' ',
                Text = v.Column_Description
            };

return query.Distinct().OrderBy(o => o.Value).AsQueryable<LevelList>();
```

Error getting this both lines of code.

```
Value =  'Level ' + LTRIM(Rtrim(Convert(Char,P.Level_Num))) + ' - ',
                    id = 'Column ' + LTRIM(Rtrim(Convert(Char,P.Column_Num))) + ' ',
```

Can any body help me out how to convert this in LINQ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can't just cut and paste SQL, rearrange it and hope to get a valid LINQ query. The aim is to write the appropriate C# code, which is *translated* into SQL. In this case I suspect you want:

```
var query = from s in bv.baParticularHeaders
            from v in bv.baPlanColumnStructures
            where x.Contains(s.Particular_Num)
            select new LevelList
            {
                Value =  "Level " + P.Level_Num + " - ";
                id = "Column " + p.Column_Num + " ",
                Text = v.Column_Description
            };

return query.Distinct().OrderBy(o => o.Value).AsQueryable();
```

Note the string literals - `"Level "` not `'Level '`. The code has to be valid C# first.

(Assuming `Level_Num` and `Column_Num` are numbers, I can't see why it would make sense to trim them.)

Comment: The OP is converting the values from a column of type 'char' which is most probably fixed length - that would at least explain the trim functions

Comment: I am getting the following error after trying Jon Skeet code

Unable to cast the type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.

Comment: @user957178: Where are you getting that error? You haven't told us anything about your data model, which really doesn't help...

Comment: Sorry about that.. here is my LevelList

    public class LevelList
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public int Code { get; set; }
    }

Comment: @user957178: And what about your database model? Do you really *need* the return type to be queryable, by the way? This would probably be significantly easier if you could return an `IEnumerable<LevelList>`.